# What is the time complexity of array initialization?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, initialization

Consider following two cases of Array initialization in C or C++ :

Case 1:

```
int array[10000] = {0}; // All values = 0
```

Case 2:

```
int array[10000];
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    array[i] = 0;
}
```

Do they both take same time ? what is the complexity of Case 1? and, Which one is better?

Comment: Is the `array` of static or automatic duration?

Comment: i was looking for both situations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the case of the array being of static duration (global variable), I'd say the first one is much preferrable, since it doesn't require any code - it is initialized by the runtime-environment.

If the variable is a of automatic duration (local variable), which one is better, if either is better than the other, depends on the compiler. Most likely, both will be very similar.

The comlexity for the automatic storage duration variable is O(n) for all cases. The first case is O(1) for a static storage duration variable.

Of course, if you wanted to fill array with the value 5, the second option is much better because it doesn't require writing 10000 `5` in the source file.

You may also find that using `memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));` is better than both - again, depending on the compiler. This is still O(n), but the actual time it takes to fill the array may be shorter, because `memset` may be better optimized than what the compiler generates for your loop case [and what it does for initialized variables]. `memset` won't work for filling the array with `5` either.

You could also use `std::fill(array, &array[10000], 5);` to set the value 5 in all the array, and the compiler will should a decent job of optimizing that.

Finally, I should point out that these sort of things only REALLY matter if they are doing in code that gets executed a lot. It's a long time since filling 40KB of data took long enough to really worry about on its own. Like 20+ years.

Comment: While `memset` can't handle setting to `5`, `std::fill` could do so nicely and can still be optimized intelligently when appropriate by a compiler.

Comment: Loop unrolling may be more efficient than `memcpy` or `std::fill`.  The idea behind the loop unrolling is to perform as many assignment operations before the branch to the top of the loop.  Branches may cause reloading of the instruction pipeline.

Comment: Yes, and compilers are pretty good at unrolling. `memset` (which I'm sure I used about and I think you mean by `memcpy`) will be unrolled to some reasonable degree. Unrolling the loop ENTIRELY, even using SSE or AVX instructions will lead to 2500 or 1250 instructions, which is surely not worth the bloat vs. the saving of a few instructions that a well-unrolled loop will do. I challenge you to find a loop where manual unrolling beats `-O3` in gcc.

Comment: @MatsPetersson gcc's `-O3` doesn't unroll loops. Whether or not loop unrolling makes a difference is fairly implementation defined. Most implementations have opcode caches, which are fairly small compared to data caches. The opcode caches vary in size, so unrolling loops (whether manually or automatically) *may* work on some systems while it *may* appear to hamper performance on another. The answer to your challenge depends upon that system.

Comment: I have certainly seen `gcc` unroll loops, but maybe you need `-funroll-loops` or something like that for that to happen. And yes, it does depend on lots of machine dependant factors.

Comment: gcc can sometimes appear to unroll loops when it hasn't exactly. For example, you call `memset` with a small constant size and see it transformed into a series of stores -- you might think this is inlining followed by loop unrolling as `-funroll-loops`, but really it's magic intrinsic `memset`.

Comment: No, I mean unrolled loops where the code in the loop is replicated a few times (I don't mean complete unrolling of large loops - like I said, that's rarely beneficial).

Comment: [This link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.4/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) might be beneficial. It tells you which optimisations are enabled by `-O3`.

Comment: Right, so following that link `-floop-optimizie`  appears to say that it "optionally do strength-reduction and loop unrolling as well". I'm guessing that this is based on some heuristics.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I think the significant quotes would be *"The compiler does not perform loop unrolling or function inlining when you specify `-O2`."* and *"`-O3` turns on all optimizations specified by `-O2` and also turns on the -finline-functions, -fweb and -frename-registers options."*.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: you might want to consult the docs for a more up to date version of gcc, though. The latest is 4.8.0, there can't be all *that* many people using 3.4.4. Although if there's some popular embedded target whose vendor ships a gcc-based compiler still at 3.4.4, there could conceivably be more people using it than are using the very latest ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Very well. [Here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) is the link for 4.8.0. Can you find anything indicating that `-O3` enables loop unrolling?

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: don't worry, my comment would have been far more smug if the optimization options in 4.8.0 were different in a way that affects the answer to the question :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop I would suggest a matter of greater significance is that some OSes clear unused regions of memory in idle time. Off the top of my head, one example is `vm.idlezero_enable` in FreeBSD.

Comment: "The first case is O(1) for a static storage duration variable." No initialization can be performed in constant time. no matter where run. you **need** to remove the bits from the memory. Whether it is your program run time or operating system does not really matter.

Comment: @lejlot: The memory needs to be allocated by the OS (or loader, or whatever you call it). It is, in most OS's, automatically filled with zero. Hence, beyond creating the space, there is nothing the OS/loader will need to do. There is, in the context of the compiler, no fill needed. It just puts the variable in .bss, and it appears into existance filled with zeros. Of course, something needs to allocate the space and it will need to be filled with SOMETHING - but assuming the OS fills with zero, it adds no extra time to use `= {0}` for a statically allocated array.

Comment: My only point is that there is no difference between OS filling it with zeros (which is O(n)) and in filling it by hand (O(n)) in the sense of **asymptotic complexity** that you are refering to. OS would do it faster, obviously, but this is not my point.

Comment: I'm not saying the OS would do it faster, I'm saying "you get it for free when you allocate the memory". You can't get memory without it being zerod. I challenge you to show me that NOT initializing with zero (for a static duration variable) is in any way faster than initializing it. Of course, it takes time to clear the memory. But it's "free" with loading the code/data into memory in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

In theory, both have the same time complexity: `O(N)`, where `N` is the size of your array.

However, the first method should be better, since it's up to the compiler to choose how to initialize as faster as possible (for instance, it could be done through `memset`). For optimizations, the compiler is very often better than the programmer.

BTW, if your array has static storage duration (if you declare it as global variable, for example), it will be auto-initialized to 0.

Comment: See also `std::fill` for C++.

Comment: Nothing stops the compiler from using memset in case 2 as well (assuming using memset is good).

Comment: @BoPersson: This is right, although is looks more difficult for the compiler to detect what we are trying to do in case 2.